# Javascript event listener "e"

Tags: javascript, binding, this, event-listener

I'm trying to get a grasp of e, this, binding. In this example, if you press the create new div button you get an elapsed time and start button. If you create multiple divs and press start on each, they are all impacted. I'm trying to make the elapsed time correspond to the button that was clicked.
I passed in "e" through out the functions but I'm not sure how to handle the next step.

**QUESTION:** Should I add let clickedButton = event.target or event.parent within the start timer function and then in the display time, would that be clickedButton.newP.innerHTML = hour_format + " :" + min_format +" : " + sec_format;
}

Below is the code:

```js
    //"create div" button with click events
    let initial = document.getElementById("test");
    initial.addEventListener("click", newPElement);
    
    
    let myTextArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
    let newP;
    
    //function that creates a P
    function newPElement(){
    newP = document.createElement("p");
    newP.classList.add("myFont");
    newP.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    myTextArea.appendChild(newP);
    
    let start =  document.createElement("button");
    start.innerText = "START";
    start.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            timer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000)
    })
    myTextArea.appendChild(start);
    
    }
    
    function startTimer(e) {
        sec++;
        if(sec === 60){
            sec === 0
            min++;
        }
    if (min === 60){
        min === 0;
        hour++;
        
    }
    displayTime(e)
    
    }
    
    //Global variables for the timer function
    let timer;
    let sec = 0;
    let min = 0;
    let hour = 0
    let newElapsedTime;
    
    
    
    function displayTime(e){
        let sec_format = sec;
        let min_format = min;
        let hour_format = hour;
     
    
      
        if(sec < 10){
            sec_format = "0"+sec;
        }
        if(min < 10){
            min_format = "0"+min;
        }
        if (hour <10){
            hour_format = "0"+hour;
        }
        newP.innerHTML = hour_format + " :" + min_format +" : " + sec_format;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Testing</h1>
        <button id="test" class="test">CREATE DIV</button>
    
        <section id="textArea">
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some scoping issues here: the variables `newP` and `sec`, `min`, `hour` are on the global scope. You only have one instance of `sec`, `min` and `hour`, which means that it is impossible to keep track of the different timers that you create. Also, every time you create a new timer, you update `newP` to point to that new element, so the old ones are "forgotten". Because of this, only the value of the most recent timer will be updated.

I would highly recommend utilizing `const` instead of `let` whenever it makes sense to do so. The value of a `const` variable can't be changed, so it will guard you against accidentally changing a value that you didn't mean to change. For example, making the `newP` variable a `const` might alert you to the fact that you're trying to reassign the value of the existing variable to a new timer element instead of creating a new variable that would be independent of the old one. I think that DOM elements are a great example of something that should (or at least could) almost always be a `const`, since usually you want them to point to the same element that you originally intended to target. Note that you can still change the element's attributes, such as `innerText`, you just can't change the DOM element that it points to, or change the variable into to an integer or something. Of course it's mostly a matter of personal preference, but I've found that for me it makes it much easier to debug things like this.

Also, the timer in your example doesn't seem to work as intended. Here's my quick take on this sort of feature, let me know if there's anything you want to ask about it!

```js
const timerContainer = document.querySelector('#timers')
const addTimerButton = document.querySelector('#add-timer')

// Note that all the new elements are scoped inside the function that gets triggered by this eventListener
addTimerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Create the new timer and start button
  const timer = document.createElement('p')
  const startButton = document.createElement('button')
  startButton.innerText = 'Start'

  // Set elapsedSeconds to 0 and initialize the timer's value
  let elapsedSeconds = 0
  updateTimerValue()

  // Add the newly created elements to the timerContainer
  timerContainer.append(startButton, timer)

  // Start the timer
  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Increment the timer every second and update the timer's text value
    setInterval(() => {
      elapsedSeconds++
      updateTimerValue()
    }, 1000)
  })

  function updateTimerValue() {
    // Count the seconds, minutes and hours, convert to strings and pad the strings with leading 0's
    const seconds = String(elapsedSeconds % 60).padStart(2, '0')
    const minutes = String(parseInt(elapsedSeconds / 60 % 60)).padStart(2, '0')
    const hours = String(parseInt(elapsedSeconds / 60 / 60)).padStart(2, '0')

    // Use string interpolation for formatting the timer string
    timer.innerText = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
  }
})
```

```css
p { margin-block: 0.2rem 0.6rem }

button {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="add-timer" type="button">Add new timer</button>
<hr>
<div id="timers"></div>
```

Comment: Wow...this works! I have no idea how you got around "bind", "this", "event" "e"...basically everything I have been trying for a week to get each button to only apply to the p tag within it's div it was created in. I'll chew on this for a while and apply it to my actual project. Thank you for taking the time to review and reply!!!

Comment: Hello, I applied your example to my actual project. However, due to the fact that I have multiple buttons that create activity divs the start button is still not tying to the corresponding p tag if more than one div is created even though I grouped everything into one function as suggested. Here is the link to the full code. Can you please see if you would approach this differently?:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72638566/setinterval-for-multiple-elments-vanilla-javascript

Comment: No problem, happy to help :) The reason you don't need `this`, `e.target` or anything like that in my example is that scoping everything related to 1 timer inside a function (block scope) will make it much easier to access the correct elements and keep track of each timer separately because you're dealing with just one set of elements inside that scope. New variables are created each time the click listener gets triggered, and they are totally separate from the variables created when the click listener was previously triggered, so "timer" will always point to the timer of the current scope.

Comment: I think GauthamV is correct in their answer to your new question: it seems to be an issue with the variable scope again. Creating a variable without a `let` `const` or `var` keyword will automatically make it global, thus making it always target the latest one again, even though it's inside the function. In order to keep it in the block scope (inside the function), declaring it with `let` or `const` should be enough.

[This article](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/variable-scope) has pretty good examples of variable scope in different situations in JavaScript.