# Vanilla javascript - binding an event listener ('click') to a dynamic element

Tags: javascript, binding, addeventlistener

Lets say you have a create button that dynamically creates a  element and a button element named play.
The play button has an eventlistener("click") that has a variable named timer that equals
set interval which runs a function named start timer that displays a time elapsed within the innerHTML of the p that was created.

**QUESTION**: Since there can be multiple timer buttons created, how can you bind the play button clicked with the p element that it was created with?

Comment: @Barmar Please reopen this question as what is being asked is not answered by the Event Delegation question you marked as a dup. The question is actually asking about how to target a dynamically created element from an event handler.

Comment: Event delegation is the way you do that.

Comment: Or you can just add the event listener to the new element after you create it. `element = document.createElement('button'); element.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: Hello @Barmar, as Scott stated, please reopen this ticket as this doesn't answer my question. The subject states Vanilla Javascript.  You closed the ticket and added a Jquery discussion that if it were vanilla javascript wouldn't help me with my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't link to a jQuery discussion, I linked to a question that's about vanilla JS.

Comment: Your follow up comment to Scott is just declaring the variable and adding the event listener. The question in bold questions binding the multiple p elements and event listeners that were created dynamically.

Comment: Please post a [mre] showing how you're creating the elements but the event listener doesn't work.

Comment: You use DOM navigation to find related elements, e.g. `event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling` if the p is the next element.

Comment: Sure @ Barmar. Please see the code in the following link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606545/javascript-event-listener-e