# Vanilla Javascript targeting child elements

Tags: javascript, binding, parent-child

Lets say you have a "create" button that dynamically creates a div, a start button, a stop button, & a p element within the div.

How can you add a function to the start buttons that bind to the p element of each div?

Would that be using the nth-child(4)? Example?

```
newPlay.addEventListener("click",function(event){
      event.target.nth-child(4)  
      timer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000); }
```

Comment: It's not clear what's meant to happen. When you click on the start button is the paragraph text meant to show an updated timer? Where's the code for `startTimer`, and the code for adding HTML?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to keep the post as simple as possible as it appears to much information leads to unanswered questions.  Yes, it shows an updated timer. My current code works for the first div that gets created but when you create multiple divs the start function impacts all the timers instead of the one that was pressed. I either need to bind them together with "this" or "event target" but I'm not sure which or how to do that. I'm still researching.

Comment: @Andy however, here is a link with code replicating the exact same issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606545/javascript-event-listener-e

Comment: `event.target.chidlren[4]`

Comment: @Barmar typo `chidlren` :)

Comment: @Andy Too late to edit. We'll have to change all the browsers to conform.

Comment: @Andy hello. I made myTarget = event.target.children[4];  however, myTarget prints as undefined.